# Angular - URL changed but view not loaded

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular5

This is my `app-routing-module.ts`

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: LayoutComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'parent',
                component: ParentComponent,
                children: [
                    { path: ':id/:name', component: ChildComponent }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
];
```

I've written a function to check if the URL is working with a static value in `parent.component.ts`.

```
goToChild() {
   this.router.navigate(['1/john'], { relativeTo: this.route });
}
```

And I call the function in the `parent.component.html`.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="goToChild()">Search</button>
```

When I click the button, I get the correct URL in the address bar,

```
 localhost:3000/parent/1/john
```

But the view never loads, it stays on the `parent.component.html`. I'm fairly new to Angular and I'm using version 5.

And if I have my routes like this, it works fine.

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: LayoutComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'parent',
                component: ParentComponent
            },
            {
                path: 'parent/:id/:name', component: ChildComponent
            }
        ]
    },
];
```

It feels more appropriate for me to put the `ChildComponent` route under children array of the `ParentComponent`, but when I do it. Only the URL changes, not the view.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` inside the template. That’s how you allow child navigation

Comment: That was my mistake, I didn't add the `router-outlet` in my parent.component.html. Thank you :)